# Workaround max equation length in APmonitor

Tags: python, gekko, apm

I am using GEKKO to find 2D-fourier coefficients of some unknown funtion u expanded in terms of 2D-vectors g. To this end have setup dictionaries and I need to calculate the many terms of the form:

```
u{ u_fourier_i_j: [m.Var(),m.Var()] ....}
g{ g_i_j : [gx_i_j, gy_i_j].....}
m.Minimize(m.cos(sup.function()))
```

where sup.function is defined as:

```
dummy = 0
for i in fourier_x:
   for j in fourier_y:
       dummy += u_fourier_i_j * np.cos(np.dot(g_i_j,[x,y]))
return dummy
```

Now I'd like to use many fourier coefficients, but Gekko gives me the error:

> APM model error: string >       15000  characters
> Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations

> The may also be due to only using newline character CR
> instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF (for MacOS/Linux)
> To fix this problem, save APM file with appropriate newline characters

Is there a way to increase the max string size in the APM Model or a way to circumvent this error all together by structuring the program differently?
Computational Ressources shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Have you tried "breaking up the line into multiple equations", as the error message suggests?

Comment: Well the whole expression of the sup.function is the argument of the cosine, so this can't reasonably broken up into multiple expressions. One could use addition theorems I guess, but this is not scalable since this breaks down at like 30 fourier coefficients and I'd like to use hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

Use `m.sum()` (gekko summation) to avoid the max length error. It takes a list input and creates a summation that improves the speed of model solution.

```py
dummy = []
for i in fourier_x:
   for j in fourier_y:
       dummy.append(u_fourier_i_j * np.cos(np.dot(g_i_j,[x,y])))
return m.sum(dummy)
```

If there is still the error, try using a similar strategy by replacing the `np.dot()` function `np.dot(g_i_j,[x,y])` with `d`:

```py
n = len(g_i_j)
z = [x,y]
d = m.sum([g_i_j[i]*z[i] for i in range(n)])
```

Please post a complete script so that the fix can be verified.